# How does Netflix show the good bye page?

Tags: reactjs, netflix

I know Netflix uses ReactJs. And when you leave the site there is a brief moment where you see a black page with the Netflix logo. I assumed it was using useEffect with a return function (hooks equivalent of componentWillUnmount) and I’ve also tried onLeave in the React Router. But I’ve not been able to duplicate it. Anyone know?

Comment: Not sure how Netflix does it but you can achieve the same effect if the black page is a background image and every component is rendered on top of it. When they are all destroyed the image is all that will remain

Comment: So. In my main index.js I would wrap everything else in a div with a wallpaper?

Comment: Or maybe in App.js?

Comment: I wouldn't use JS. Just normal old school HTML/CSS on the page which will still be there when all JS is disposed of

Comment: Okay. So like in my Public index.html?

Answer (score 0):

My guess will be that they are using a WindowEventHandlers event [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) which is triggered when you navigate off the site or close the tab.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
 //code
})
```